# Call method from top class in hierarchy instead of override

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have classes `Base(object)` and `Derived(Base)`. These both implement a function `foo`, with `Derived.foo` overriding the version in `Base`.

However, in one of the methods, say `Base.learn_to_foo`, I want to call `Base.foo` instead of the derived version regardless of whether it was overridden. So, I call `Base.foo(self)` in that method:

```
class Base(object):
    # ...

    def learn_to_foo(self, x):
        y = Base.foo(self, x)
        # check if we foo'd correctly, do interesting stuff
```

This approach seems to work and from a domain standpoint, it makes perfect sense, but somehow it smells a bit fishy. Is this the way to go, or should I refactor?

Comment: Why override `foo` in the first place, in a way that makes it unsuitable as replacement for `Base.foo`?

Comment: @delnan: because it is suitable as a replacement everywhere *except* in `learn_to_foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **NOT** to use the `super()` function. The way you are doing is exactly right as you don't want to invoke the virtual method that is overridden in the super class. Since you seem to want the base class' exact implementation all the time, the only way is to get the base class' **unbound** method object back, bound it to `self`, which could be an instance of `Base` or `Derived`. Invoke the unbound method with `self` supplied explicitly as the first parameter gives you back a **bound** method. From this point forward, `Base.foo` will be acting on the instance `self`'s data. This is perfectly acceptable and is the way Python deals with non-virtual method invocation. This is one of the nice things that Python allows you to do that Java does not.

Comment: Thanks. Could you perhaps point me to any examples of this idiom in other code?

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended:

```
def learn_to_foo(self, x):
  super(Derived, self).foo(x)
```

More information at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Calling super like that, the `self` doesn't need to be explictly specified. [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super)

Comment: You was writting it and I was fixing the text, anyway thank you :-)

Comment: This is what I'd to in `Derived`. But the point is, I'm calling `Base.foo` *in a method of `Base`* and don't want that to call overrides. I've updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been voted up 3 times as it clearly does not address the problem @larsmans is asking.

Comment: I gave an answer for what he had asked at the first moment, after he explained another thing. Only after he edited the question that became clear that he is not at Derived class.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the 'super' built-in:

```
super(Derived, self).foo(x)     # Python 2

super().foo(x)                  # Python 3
```

Comment: Nope, same problem that I described in the comment at Pih's answer: we're not in `Derived`.

Comment: Apologies.  Maybe you should have two methods in the Base class, one which does the Base foo functionality (say, called __Basefoo) and another foo which just calls __Basefoo, but can be overridden.  In learn_to_foo we call __Basefoo.

Comment: Calling Base.foo() explicitly is not all that bad, but cdarke's solution here is also a very nice workaround. The need to do this smells a bit funny to me, though; generally polymorphism is a Good Thing.

Comment: @jtniehof: the use case is the training algorithm for averaged perceptrons (`Derived.learn_to_foo`), part of which is to do prediction as if the averaged perceptron were an ordinary perceptron (`Base.foo`). However, outside of the training algorithm, prediction should be done with a more complex algorithm (`Derived.foo`).