# Python 3 inheritance same as in C++

Tags: c++, python, inheritance

I have:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func_X(self):
        print("Class A: X")

        self.func_Y()

    def func_Y(self):
        print("Class A: Y")
        print("Why does not work?")


class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

    def func_Y(self):
        print("Class B: Y")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    TEST = B()
    TEST.func_X()

OUTPUT:

Class A: X
Class B: Y
```

Question: Why works "B.func_Y", but not "A.func_Y"? This is bug? How to fix it? I need this to work same as in C++. C++ analog:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
      void func_X() {cout<<"Class A: X"<<endl; func_Y();}
      void func_Y() {cout<<"Class A: Y"<<endl;}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
      void func_Y() {cout<<"Class B: Y"<<endl;}
};


int main(void)
{
    B TEST = B();
    TEST.func_X();

    return 0;
}

OUTPUT:

Class A: X
Class A: Y
```

I faced this problem for a long time, but have not found a solution. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that in Python functions are `virtual`. If you need it to behave differently, you need to design it differently. C++ and Python are not the same languages, and will behave differently from each other. Deal with it.

Comment: What are you asking?  In what way does `A.func_Y` "not work"?  You don't even call `A.func_Y` in your code.

Comment: @BrenBarn: It's called in `A.func_X`

Comment: @Blender: That's not calling `A.func_Y`, it's calling `self.func_Y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you call `func_Y()` on `self`. This would probably be the equivalent in C++ of calling `func_Y()` on `this`.

Look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871542/call-method-from-top-class-in-hierarchy-instead-of-override).

It seems that you should do a `A.func_Y()` or a call to `super` instead of `self.func_Y()`.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: That should be `A.func_Y(self)`.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  In Python, when calling from within a member, you have to use `self.function()`; in C++, this would be `this->function();`, except that the `this->` is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

Python resolves *everything* at run time, using the dynamic
type.  C++ resolves almost everything at compile time, using the
static type.  If you want dynamic type resolution, you must tell
the compiler this *in the static type*.  In this case, declare
`func_Y` `virtual` in the base class, and it should work as in
Python.

The way name lookup works is actually significantly different
in Python and in C++, but in simple cases, the practical results
are as if all members in Python were declared virtual in C++.
Except that in C++, only functions can be declared virtual; in
Python, dynamic lookup affects *all* members.